# "checkwarns" command giving me this error

Tags: discord.js

Whenever I use my `checkwarns` command to check the number of warns a user has it gives me this error:

```
2019-03-20T23:55:35.590941+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'warns' of 
undefined
2019-03-20T23:55:35.590958+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at 
Object.module.exports.run (/app/commands/checkwarns.js:10:35)
```

I don't know how to fix this I can't find any problems with my code.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const ms = require("ms");
let warns = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./warnings.json", "utf8"));

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return
  message.reply("You don't have permssion to use this command");
  let wUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first()) ||
    message.guild.members.get(args[0])
  if (!wUser) return message.reply("Couldn't find that user");
  let warnlevel = warns[wUser.id].warns;

  if (!warns[wUser.id]) warns[wUser.id] = {
    warns: 0
  };

  message.delete().catch();

  let warnembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("**warns**")
    .setColor("#0xff80ff")
    .addField("User Warns", warnlevel, true);

  message.channel.send(warnembed);
}

module.exports.help = {
  name: "checkwarns"
}
```

I'm using Heroku to host the bot.

Comment: What does a `warns` object look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue might be occuring here:

```
let warnlevel = warns[wUser.id].warns;
```

If the key `wUser.id` doesn't exist, the value of `warns[wUser.id]` would be `undefined`, which doesn't contain any user-defined properties. Hence, you get an error trying to read the value of `warns` (a user-defined property) in `undefined`.

To get around this, you want to check whether an object at `warns[wUser.id]` actually exists first. An easy way to do this is by doing the following:

```
var warnLevel;

if (warns[wUser.id] != undefined) {
    warnLevel = warns[wUser.id].warns
}
else {
    // Do something else to initialize either warnLevel or warns[wUser.id] here
}
```